# OCaml : type constraints in signatures

Tags: types, ocaml, signature, type-constraints

In my code, I have a **database access context** that provides elementary read/write operations, called `CouchDB.ctx`. Various modules in my application then extend that class with additional functionality, such as `Async.ctx`.

I am implementing a `Cache` module which is wrapped around a `Source` module. The `Cache` module functions take a context argument and manipulate the database. Some calls are then forwarded to the `Source` module along with the context.

I need to define a functor along the lines of this:

```
module CouchDB = struct
  class ctx = object
    method get : string -> string option monad 
    method put : string -> string -> unit monad
  end
end

module AsyncDB = struct
  class ctx = object
    inherit CouchDB.ctx
    method delay : 'a. float -> (ctx -> 'a monad) -> 'a monad 
  end
end

module type SOURCE = sig
  class ctx = #CouchDB.ctx (* <-- incorrect *)
  type source
  val get : source -> ctx -> string monad
end

module Cache = functor(S:SOURCE) -> struct
  class ctx = S.ctx
  type source = S.source
  let get source ctx = 
    bind (ctx # get source) (function 
     | Some cache -> return cache
     | None -> 
       bind (S.get source ctx) 
         (fun data -> bind (ctx # put source data) 
                        (fun () -> return data)) 
end

module SomeSource = struct
  class ctx = AsyncDB.ctx
  type source = string
  let get s ctx = 
    ctx # async 300 (some_long_computation s)
end

module SomeCache = Cache(SomeSource)
```

The problem is that I cannot express the fact that the context used by the `Source` module should be a subtype of `CouchDB.ctx`. The above code returns the error:

```
A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type #CouchDB.ctx as 'a the variable 'a is unbound
```

How do I express this type constraint ?

Comment: I'm curious about your `SOURCE` signature. The declaration in my mind should be `module type SOURCE = sig class ctx : object inherit CouchDB.ctx end (* ... *) end`; does this not do what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Obsolete...

The closest you can get is defining the signature as:

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  type 'a ctx = 'a constraint 'a = #CouchDB.ctx
  type source
  val get : source -> 'a ctx -> string 
end
```

But of course, you could as well just write:

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  type source
  val get : source -> #CouchDB.ctx -> string 
end
```

Edit: Note that OCaml uses *structural* typing for objects. That means that even if you wanted, you cannot get any more restrictive than the above. It does not even limit arguments to `get` to be instances of `CouchDB.ctx` or a derived class -- any object that has (at least) the same methods will be compatible. Even when you write

```
  val get : source -> CouchDB.ctx -> string
```

you can pass *any* object that has the same methods. The type `CouchDB.ctx` is just an abbreviation for a specific structural object type that happens to match the objects generated by the class of the same name. It is not restricted to those. And just to be sure: that is considered a feature.

======]

Edit 2: With the extended example, I now see what you want and why. Unfortunately, that isn't possible directly in OCaml. You would need *partially abstract* types. Namely, you would need to be able to write

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  type ctx < CouchDB.ctx
  ...
end
```

This is not available in OCaml. However, you can get close if you are willing to provide an explicit upcast in the signature:

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  type ctx
  val up : ctx -> CouchDB.ctx
  type source = string
  val get : source -> ctx -> string monad
end
```

Then, in `Cache`, you have to replace occurrences of `ctx#get` with `(S.up ctx)#get`, and likewise for `ctx#put`.

```
module Cache = functor (S:SOURCE) -> struct
  type ctx = S.ctx
  type source = S.source
  let get source ctx = 
     bind ((S.up ctx)#get source) ...
end

module SomeSource = struct
  type ctx = AsyncDB.ctx
  let up ctx = (ctx : ctx :> CouchDB.ctx)
  type source = string
  let get s ctx = ...
end

module SomeCache = Cache (SomeSource)
```

Note that I also made `type source = string` transparent in the signature `SOURCE`. Without that, I cannot see how `ctx#get source` can possibly type-check in the `Cache` functor.

Comment: I don't get how I could make the first examle fit with my situation (my context class has zero parameters). The second version is incorrect, since it would expect `Source.get` to accept *any* subclass of `CouchDB.ctx`, when in fact it only accepts *one* (`Async.ctx`).

Comment: Well, why do you *want* to restrict `Source.get` like that? As far as I can see, that isn't necessary, nor does it buy anything (all subtyping is purely structural in OCaml, even if you use class names). I would recommend not trying to force some form of nominal subtyping onto OCaml, as that is not how the language works. OCaml favours structural typing over nominal, and polymorphism over subtyping. Only constrain types if that is necessary for type checking.

Comment: That type was constrained for *illustration purposes*. In my actual code base, that constraint was inferred from the body of the function, which is obviously more complex than what is presented here. I am trying to present my problem without copy-pasting the actual thousands of lines from my code. Since using type constraints for illustration purposes is confusing, I have edited the code above for additional clarification.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand what you're up to. Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: I see. This is what I had used as a temporary solution, but it looks like it will become permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're after then this should do the trick:

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  class ctx : CouchDB.ctx
  type source
  val get : source -> ctx -> string
end
```

`class ctx : CouchDB.ctx` is a [class-specification](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual017.html#class-specification). The OCaml docs describe them as

> This is the counterpart in signatures of class definitions. A class specification matches a class definition if they have the same type parameters and their types match.

There's also this

```
module type SOURCE = sig
  class type ctx = CouchDB.ctx
  type source
  val get : source -> ctx -> string
end
```

which is subtly different. The former requires a real class definition in the module which the latter accepts a class definition or a classtype definition (i.e. a class type alias).

Comment: I have updated my question to include an example of use of the functor, so that you can also compile it. Your solutions prevented `SomeSource` from matching the `SOURCE` signature, because they do not allow `ctx = Async.ctx` either as classes or class types.